# How to format zero in MomentJS

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I am using MomentJS in AngularJS to format date. I am receiving sometimes "0" and moment returns "01/01/2000"
How can i change it so i can get string like "there is no date" or a least "0"

I thought about .IsValid() but it accepets "0" (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/)

```
angular.module('myModule').filter('myDateFilter', function() {

    return function(date) {

        return isNaN(date) ? date : moment('' + date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

    };
```

edit: tested on google chrome, IE works fine

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
angular.module('myModule').filter('myDateFilter', function() {

    return function(date) {

        var dateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            isValid = moment(date, dateFormat, true).isValid();

        return isValid ? moment('' + date).format(dateFormat) : 'there is no date';

    }});
```

For further read:
https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/date-validation-using-moment.js.html